# How do I run a function when two buttons are click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, onclick, buttonclick

I wanted to know how to run a function when two buttons are clicked in JavaScript. What I mean is the if one of the buttons is clicked and the other is not the function will not run but only when those two are pressed then it works.

Comment: This is very doable! Can you provide some minimal code that you have tried already before we help you out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope, this is what you want :)

```js
let firstButtonClicked = false
let secondButtonClicked = false

function Handler(){
  firstButtonClicked = false
  secondButtonClicked = false
  console.log('this is your function you want to run only after 2 button is clicked')
}
button_1.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  firstButtonClicked = true
  if(firstButtonClicked && secondButtonClicked) Handler()
})
button_2.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  secondButtonClicked = true
  if(firstButtonClicked && secondButtonClicked) Handler()
})
```

```html
<button id='button_1'>button_1</button>
<button id='button_2'>button_2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for a desktop / laptop a user will only be able to click one button at a time. But if you are using multi touches on a mobile device you should keep track of two booleans, if button one or two is pressed run a function that sets the boolean connected to the button to true, and checks whether boolean 1 && boolean 2 equals true, if it is true you can run your function. Just make sure to turn the boolean that is connected to the button should be set to false when the user releases the button.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could include some sample code. Something that illustrates how to put this logic into a click-handler.